# Trigonometric identity involving double angles

Tags: trigonometry

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are acute angles and $\displaystyle{\cos2\alpha=\frac{3\cos\beta-1}{3-\cos2\beta}}$, then prove that $\displaystyle{\tan\alpha=\sqrt{2}\tan\beta}$.

I tried this question by taking the formula of $\cos2\alpha$ in terms of $\tan$ (which is of degree two) but I couldn't prove it. Please suggest some hints.

Comment: typo I think...

cos b must be cos 2B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) in either sides.

$$\dfrac{1-\tan^2\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}=\frac{3\cdot\dfrac{1-\tan^2\beta}{1+\tan^2\beta}-1}{3-\dfrac{1-\tan^2\beta}{1+\tan^2\beta}}$$

$$\implies\dfrac{1-\tan^2\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}=\frac{2-4\tan^2\beta}{2+4\tan^2\beta}$$

Using [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo), $$\frac{\tan^2\alpha}1=\frac{4\tan^2\beta}2$$

Comment: @user124672, How about this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be false. If those equations are true, then these two equations should be equivalent to each other:

$$\alpha  = \frac{1}{2}\arccos \left( {\frac{{3\cos \beta  - 1}}{{3 - \cos 2\beta }}} \right)$$

$$\alpha  = \arctan \left( {\sqrt 2 \tan \beta } \right)$$

But when I graph those equations for varying $\beta$ the graphs are not at all equal.

[image]

Comment: @ Rory Daulton, is there any assumption or ammendment to make this correct .

Comment: @user124672: Yes. As others have pointed out since my post, changing the first equation to $\displaystyle{\cos2\alpha=\frac{3\cos2\beta-1}{3-\cos2\beta}}$ corrects the problem. Is that the proper correction? Only you have the original problem!

Answer (score 1):

HINT

If I assume              cos B is  cos 2B

then write cos2B= 1 - 2 {sin(B) }^2

then divide both numerator and denominator by {cos^2 (B)}^2 and then use (secB)^2 = 1 + (tanB)^2

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\cos\pars{2\alpha}={3\cos\pars{2\beta} - 1 \over 3 - \cos\pars{2\beta}}\quad
     \imp\quad \tan\pars{\alpha} = \root{2}\tan\pars{\beta}:\ {\large ?}}$

> $$
> \cos\pars{2\alpha}={3\cos\pars{2\beta} - 1 \over 3 - \cos\pars{2\beta}}\
> \imp\ {\cos\pars{2\alpha} + 1 \over \cos\pars{2\alpha} - 1}
> ={\bracks{3\cos\pars{2\beta} - 1} + \bracks{3 - \cos\pars{2\beta}} \over \bracks{3\cos\pars{2\beta} - 1} - \bracks{3 - \cos\pars{2\beta}}}
> $$

$$
{2 - 2\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha} \over 2\cos^{2}\pars{\alpha} - 2}
={2\cos\pars{2\beta} + 2 \over 4\cos\pars{2\beta} - 4}
={\cos\pars{2\beta} + 1 \over 2\cos\pars{2\beta} - 2}
={2 - 2\sin^{2}\pars{\beta} \over 4\cos^{2}\pars{\beta} - 4}
$$

> $$
> {\cos^{2}\pars{\alpha} \over -\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha}}
> ={\sec^{2}\pars{\beta} - \tan^{2}\pars{\beta} \over 2 - 2\sec^{2}\pars{\beta}}
> ={1 \over -2\tan^{2}\pars{\beta}}\ \imp\
> \boxed{\quad\tan^{2}\pars{\alpha} = 2\tan^{2}\pars{\beta}\quad}
> $$

$$
\color{#66f}{\large\tan\pars{\alpha} = \pm\root{2}\tan\pars{\beta}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If the equation is $$\cos 2\alpha = \frac {3\cos 2\beta -1}{3-\cos 2 \beta}$$ Your method can make progress as follows: first let $t=\tan \alpha$ so that $\cos 2\alpha = \cfrac {1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and clear fractions - (let $c=\cos 2\beta$) so $$(1-t^2)(3-c)=(1+t^2)(3c-1)$$ so that $$4(1-c)=2(1+c)t^2$$ Now use  $c=\cos 2\beta = \cos^2 \beta- \sin^2\beta$ and $1=\cos^2 \beta+ \sin^2\beta$

You will need the condition that the angles are acute to get the right sign for the square root.